# How to move the list-view header to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, performance-testing

**Expected behavior:**

I have got a playerview on top of the screen followed by a stick view below the player view.At the bottom of the screen there is also a listview as shown in the attached image.What i need is,while we scroll the screen up and when the playerview completely vanishes it(Player view) should come to the bottom of the screen as scale animation.Stick view should stay at the top as a header and we should be able to scroll the listview items.When we scrolldown the listview the player view should come on the top as before.

========================================================================

please go through the attached images

[image]

**My Current implementation:**

I have used a listview for creating the User interface and it has been succesfull to a great extend.But am stuck with a doubt.I have implemented the player view as a header of the LISTVIEW.The Stick view is created using the technique ListView-Scroll-Sync which is explained in the below given link       https://github.com/gh123man/Partial-Header-ListView-Scroll-Sync).Everything.But the problem am facing is how to move the player view from the top to the bottom of the screen using scale animation.Is it possible to move the listview header to the bottom of the screen.Its somewhat similar to youtube app but not fully.So I cant use the following library (not sure )https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

If there is another way to create this kind of view let me know.please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following library:

https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

May it help you.